I can't add previous input image file after i delete it
i have very strange problem here. I've input type="file" and when i add image it adds ofc and when i click delete it deleted, but i can't add same image while i dont add different image.
i.e. i can't add same image after i delete it
 <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          alt="upload image"
          className="product-images-input"
          name="image"
          onChange={e => handleAddImages({ target: e.target })}
          multiple
          hidden
          ref={filesRef}
        />

There is functions of adding items and remove item
  const handleAddImages = ({ target: { files } }) => {
    for (const file of files) {
      const newImg = {
        url: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        name: file.name,
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      };
      dispatch(addImages([...images, newImg]));
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteImg = id => {
    const newImages = images.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    dispatch(deleteImg(newImages));
  };

I don't get it where i'm wrong, please help me
const initialState = {
  productFields: {
    images: [],
  },
};

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addImages: (state, action) => {
      const payload = action.payload;
      state.productFields.images = payload;
    },
    deleteImg: (state, action) => {
      const payload = action.payload;
      state.productFields.images = payload;
    },
  },
});


Probably when you click "delete" (it is not clear how you are doing this because you have not provided the deletion control code) you are not cleared the selected value in the <input> element so it retain the previously selected value.
Therefore when you select the same file again, the selected file become the same as before and the "change" event is not raised because there is no any change in its value.
I see two options how to fix it:

Explicitly clear the <input> element value after file deletion
Use "input" event instead of "change"


Okey let's talk about option 1. it works when i have only one picture, but if i have more than one picture, it doesn't work, because when i click delete button and i clear input value, it's empty yes, but one picture will be there. so... if i press submit, my backend won't upload nothing.
